# Получение данных от Web App Telegram aiogram 3.0

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот, web-apps

Делаю кастомную форму в web app telegram,и когда при нажатии на кнопку Сохранить отправляю данные в виде строки от веб-приложения к боту с поvощью Senddata(), строка приходит, но не понятно, как её отловить, не нашёл в инете ни одного примера, хотя вроде как технологии уже год. Если писать просто @dp.message() или @route.messsage строка приходит, но тогда не примешь остальные текстовые сообщения. Как отловить данные через хэндэлер или какой-то фильтр?

Answer (score 0):

Тоже не нашел, поэтому так:

```html
from typing import Union, Dict, Any
from aiogram.filters import Filter
from aiogram.types import Message

class WebAppDataFilter(Filter):
    async def __call__(self, message: Message, **kwargs) -> Union[bool, Dict[str, Any]]:
        return dict(web_app_data=message.web_app_data) if message.web_app_data else False

#... Инициализация бота

@dp.message(WebAppDataFilter())
async def handle_web_app_data(message: types.Message, web_app_data: types.WebAppData):
    print(web_app_data)
    await message.answer("Received web app data")
```